# jQuery - plugin methods call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a jQuery plugin following some official [best practices](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

```
(function($){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) {
      this.options = options;
    }
  , add_that: function (elem) {
      this.append(elem);
      return (this);
    }
  , add_this: function (elem) {
      return (methods.add_that(elem));
    }
  };

  $.fn.test = function (method) { 
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.test' );
    }    
  };

})(jQuery);
```

I'd like the method `add_that` to be able to append things to the matched element(s).
Now this method is called from `add_this`.

```
$('#test').test('add_this', $('<div />'));
```

> TypeError: this.append is not a function

Why can't I access to the plugin (`this`) from `add_that` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the scope has changed when you've called it from `add_this`. Notice that the original call used `Function.apply` to scope the call to `this`.

```
if ( methods[method] ) {
  return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
}
```

So you can presumably get around the issue by using apply again in your method:

```
add_this: function (elem) {
  return methods.add_that.apply(this,[elem]);
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/XaUHV/

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to make my [first](https://github.com/Glideh/jquery.particles.burst) githubbed jquery plugin :)

Answer (score 2):

In the context you're using it "this" refers to methods.add_that

Since methods.add_that is a function there is no method on it called "append" by default.